# Valgrind detected wrong allocation on heap?

Tags: c++, debugging, memory, valgrind, heap-memory

I wrote a C++ program that ran correctly over valgrind but I have notices something really strange:

```
==23369== HEAP SUMMARY:
==23369==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23369==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 72,704 bytes allocated
```

Where this allocation came from?
I only called `sbrk()` and `mmap()` but never used `malloc` or `new` so how can I know what is causing this?

---

**Update:** I removed `#include <iostream>` and it worked! Still I didn't get why is this. I just included a library which I didn't use... (I have cassert and removing `#include <iostream>` caused no problems

Comment: You didn't, but maybe the C library did.

Comment: You might be surprised, as code you use may internally allocate.  Can you show actual code?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik please notice the update

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis question was updated, this is really strange :)

Comment: So, your C++ library's header file declares an object, for some reason, that pulls in some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to debug your program(We need to install the debug symbol for libstdc++ at first, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55718257/using-standard-c-library-debug-symbols-ubuntu-linux-libstdc6-8-dbg)):

1. start the program with gdb

```
gdb $YOUR_PROGRAM
```

2. Add debug breakpoint

```
b malloc
```

3. Run the program

```
r
```

4. Get the call trace after hitting breakpoint:

```
bt
```

On my PC with this nearly empty program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { return 0; }
```

We get the call trace only once (Same as the OP, and the size 72,704 is exactly the same!):

```
#0  __GI___libc_malloc (bytes=bytes@entry=72704) at malloc.c:3043
#1  0x00007ffff7e2eb8a in (anonymous namespace)::pool::pool (
    this=0x7ffff7fc3b40 <(anonymous namespace)::emergency_pool>)
    at ../../../../src/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_alloc.cc:123
#2  __static_initialization_and_destruction_0 (__priority=65535, __initialize_p=1)
    at ../../../../src/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_alloc.cc:262
#3  _GLOBAL__sub_I_eh_alloc.cc(void) ()
    at ../../../../src/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_alloc.cc:338
#4  0x00007ffff7fdfdbe in ?? () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#5  0x00007ffff7fdfea8 in ?? () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#6  0x00007ffff7fcf10a in ?? () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

If we remove the `#include <iostream>`, we won't hit the `malloc` again!
Now we confirmed that the malloc is called by libstdc++(The STL) library itself.

There is a global object `emergency_pool` in STL, which will call `malloc` during destructing to [reserve memory](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/releases/gcc-10/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_alloc.cc#L262), if we include `iostream` it will be constructed before `main`.